# Is there a way to add performance counter in Azure Log Analytics from command line

Tags: azure-log-analytics

Is there a way to added performance counter in Azure Log Analytics using Powershell or azure CLI. The only options I see are for querying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my research, we can use PowerShell command `new-azoperationalinsightswindowsperformancecounterdatasource` to add windows performance counter. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.operationalinsights/new-azoperationalinsightswindowsperformancecounterdatasource?view=azps-3.5.0).
For example

```
Connect-AzAccount
$workspace=Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace -ResourceGroupName jimtest -Name hybridWorkspace32979
New-AzOperationalInsightsWindowsPerformanceCounterDataSource -Workspace $workspace -Name "test" -ObjectName ".NET CLR Loading" -CounterName "Total Appdomains" -InstanceName "*" -IntervalSeconds 10
Get-AzOperationalInsightsDataSource -ResourceGroupName jimtest -WorkspaceName hybridWorkspace32979 -Kind WindowsPerformanceCounter
```

[image]
[image]

Besides, if you want to add Linux performance counter, you can use the command `New-AzOperationalInsightsLinuxPerformanceObjectDataSource` and `Enable-AzOperationalInsightsLinuxPerformanceCollection`. For more details, please refer to the [article](https://www.systemcenterautomation.com/2020/01/azure-monitor-alerting-at-scale-iaas/)

Comment: where you able to find anything using azure cli?

Comment: @kumar As far as I knew, Azure CLI does not provide similar command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/log-analytics?view=azure-cli-latest