# Azure Log Analytics - Copy Performance Counters between Workspaces

Tags: azure-log-analytics

I set up a Log Analytics workspace for one of my servers and I manually added several performance counters.

Is there a fast way to copy the performance counters to future workspaces, or do I have to manually add them each time?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to copy Performance Counters between LA workspace, however you can automate the process using PowerShell. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60302331/is-there-a-way-to-add-performance-counter-in-azure-log-analytics-from-command-li) is a SO thread where one of the community member has provided sample solution on how to add the performance counter using PowerShell.

Another article for your reference: [Create workspace and configure data sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/powershell-workspace-configuration#create-workspace-and-configure-data-sources).